# Suppressing GC memory optimization

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, defragmentation

I'm writing a program that invokes multiple C based functions (p/Invoke) in multiple threads.

From time to time, the program crashes with a access violation error. My first thought was that the GC optimized the memory and moved the chunk of memory, that the C function was working on, to a different location.

What I would like to do is have the GC working but disable the part where it moves (defrags) memory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You probably cannot do that, and it would be implementation specific if you did manage to make it nearly work. (So it won't work on Mono, for example). Moving live data is an essential property of copying generational garbage collector. Read at least http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Are you aware you can pin memory in P/Invoke scenarios? http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/05/memory-control.html

Comment: I'm using P/Invoke and also use AllocHGGlobal to pin the object before calling to the C function. Still from time to time I get crashes. When I run the program in Debug there are no crashes. Is there a place I can read the difference in GC operation in Debug and Release mode?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like your problem is not related to GC at all.  It sounds more like a basic threading bug in your code.  Debug builds do not change the behavior of the GC significantly, if at all, but do change the behavior of pretty much everything else.  That might be worth considering.

Answer (score 5):

As other answers have said, the first thing to do is to ensure that you are pinning objects correctly.  Assuming you have done that, what else can go wrong?

```
class C
{
    public int handle;
    ...
    ~C() { InteropLibrary.DestroyHandle(handle); }
}

void M()
{
    C c = GetSomeObjectUsefulInUnmanagedCode();
    D d = InteropLibrary.UnmanagedMethodThatUsesHandle(c);
    // COMMENT
    d.DoSomethingWithStoredHandle();
}
```

What if a garbage collection happens at `COMMENT` (*)? The garbage collector is free to say "hey, local variable `c` is never referenced again in this method; I can be aggressive and treat it as dead!". If the finalizer runs and the handle is destroyed then when the last method runs, it accesses a destroyed handle and crashes.

To solve this rare but possible problem you can use `GC.KeepAlive` to tell the garbage collector to be less aggressive about cleaning up a particular reference. If you keep `c` alive until the end of the method then you know its destructor cannot possibly run.

---

(*) Of course the GC runs on a different thread, and can run at any time. The details of what operations are and are not interruptable by a GC are complicated and you shouldn't rely on those sorts of implementation details for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fixed` keyword in most cases.

From Eric Lippert's new [blog](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/11/taking-responsibility/) it seems there are at least two other possibilities:

- using a [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) to allocate memory
- using an external unmanaged allocator like [AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal.aspx)

Note that in these two options require you to ensure the memory is correctly deallocated.

On a side note, if your problem is that a tiny bit of memory is moved around (causing access violations) then the solution is almost never to disable the *entire* moving-memory-around part.

Comment: I do pin the objects before sending them to the C function. I still get crashes from time to time.

Comment: @Gilad Then you should fix the error by figuring out why exacly does it crash, not trying to work around it by limiting the GC.

Comment: I'm not trying to work around it, I'm trying to verify that this is the problem.

Comment: @Gilad Can you post the relevant code around your p/invoke and the line where you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this globally, but you can use the `fixed` keyword to pin specific objects, with the desired effect.